# Python - Class Property.Setter does not validate a direct set on dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary, oop, python-descriptors

Please refer to the function `main():` the results are mentioned as comments. *General note: When `Class()` has an `attribute` containing e.g. `str` -> the `@propery.setter` will validate once set.

However, when I am storing a `dictionary` in the `Class.attribute`, My `@property.setter` is not working if I directly set a `key : value`

```
class CoinJar():

    def __init__(self):
        self._priceDict = {'current' : 0.0, 'high' : 0.0, 'low' : 0.0}
        self.klines = {}
        self.volume = {}

    def __str__(self):
        return f'\n\U0001F36A'

    @property
    def priceDict(self):
        return self._priceDict

    @priceDict.setter
    def priceDict(self, priceDict):

        print('setting price')

        try:
            newPrice = float(priceDict.get('current'))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f'Input cannot be converted to float {e}')

        # Exceptions
        if len(priceDict.keys()) == 0 or newPrice == None or type(newPrice) not in [int, float]:
            raise ValueError('setting illegal value')

        #setting high, low, current
        self._priceDict['current'] = newPrice

        if newPrice > self._priceDict['high']:
            self._priceDict['high'] = newPrice
        if newPrice < self._priceDict['low'] or self._priceDict['low'] == 0.0:
            self._priceDict['low'] = newPrice


def main():
    btc = CoinJar()
    btc.priceDict = {'current' : 500}           # This is calling priceDict.setter => accepts and performs the .setter expressions
    btc.priceDict['flamingo'] = 20              # This is not calling priceDict.setter => can do what i want, with 'current, high, flamingo, *'
    btc.priceDict = {'flamingo' : 500}          # This is calling priceDict.setter => raises Exception (as expected)
    print(btc)

def retrieveData():
    ...

def analyseData():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `btc.priceDict['flamingo']` doesnt call the setter at all. You're calling `__setitem__` on a dict instance.

Comment: Yes, I noticed, but why is it not using the setter method for this case? I am changing the dictionary by accessing the class attributes.__setitem__ In this way, using a dictionary in a @setter way has not much use if someone can screw the Obj <values>.. ?

Comment: sounds like you want something like a `FrozenDict`, is that right?

Comment: You are conflating two different things. The `@setter` decorator wraps assigning to `priceDict` entirely. e.g. `btc.priceDict = {}`. It doesnt do anything with the attributes on the dict returned from the property (in this case the `__setitem__` attribute). If you want to override updating an element in the dict (such as `btc.priceDict['flamingo'] = 20`), you would need a custom class that extends dict where you can override `__setitem__`.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at this simplified example:

```
class AClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._some_dict = None

    @property
    def some_dict(self):
        print('getting')
        return self._some_dict

    @some_dict.setter
    def some_dict(self, value):
        print('setting')
        self._some_dict = value


an_obj = AClass()
an_obj.some_dict = {}  # setter gets called
an_obj.some_dict['a_key'] = 1  # getter gets called, as dict is being accessed
```

A property setter for an attribute gets called when the value of the attribute itself needs to be set. I.e. when you assign a new dictionary to the attribute for a `dict` attribute.

A property getter gets called when the attribute is accessed ('read' / 'gotten').

The setter does not get called when you manipulate the attribute otherwise, like setting a key or value for the dictionary. You could trigger on that, but you'd have to override the dictionary.

Something like this:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, *args, **kwargs):
        print('setting a dictionary value')
        super().__setitem__(key, *args, **kwargs)


class AClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._some_dict = None

    @property
    def some_dict(self):
        print('getting')
        return self._some_dict

    @some_dict.setter
    def some_dict(self, value):
        print('setting')
        self._some_dict = MyDict(value)


an_obj = AClass()
an_obj.some_dict = {}  # setter gets called
an_obj.some_dict['a_key'] = 1  # getter gets called, as well as item setter

# Note: this just calls setter, as it just directly sets the attribute to the new dict:
an_obj.some_dict = {'a_key': 1}
```

Another thing to note is that the above doesn't automatically work recursively. That is, if your dictionary contains further dictionaries, they are not automatically turned into `MyDict`, so this happens:

```
an_obj = AClass()
an_obj.some_dict = {}  # setter
an_obj.some_dict['a_key'] = {}  # getter and item setter
an_obj.some_dict['a_key']['another_key'] = 1  # only getter
```

You can keep adding functionality, by having the `MyDict` turn any `dict` value into a `MyDict`, but there's further issues to consider - adjust as needed:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value, *args, **kwargs):
        print('setting a dictionary value')
        if isinstance(value, dict) and not isinstance(value, MyDict):
            value = MyDict(value)
        super().__setitem__(key, value, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! you mention "further issues to consider" - I am thinking about i.e. if a list is set as item instead of a dict? What would also mean, I am able to control the other instances as well. Does this also imply that if AClass().list = [dict, dict] , I have to define a separate class AList() to at least have this same method applied to? Assuming I can superclass the function __setitem__ in this AList Class as well?

Comment: That's one example. Another would be: what if a `dict` gets assigned as a value that already has other `dict`s in it, you'd probably have to traverse it and reassign those values - etc. It gets pretty hairy, so I wouldn't focus on covering all cases but asking yourself what the useful cases are, where you need it to work correctly.

Comment: Part of why there isn't a standard class like this is likely that, to cover all possible cases, a lot of overhead is added, whether you're using it or not. Also, it's not always obvious that something should work a specific way - the example you gave is a good one. *Should* all dictionaries in lists be replaced with these modified ones? Or should it be up to the user of your classes to decide where and when to apply them? Since each bit of functionality is relatively easy to implement in Python, it makes more sense to give you solid basic classes and allow you to add what you need.

Comment: Hmm I understand. This grows as a spider web where each step, sub-step, etc. should at least me thought over before implementation. A FrozenDict which was proposed by rv.kvetch below can still be of use here. Is it too easy to think that they could have added an extra ((**kw) in all __classes__ (and subsequent __meth/atr__) which would set immutability of some sort?

Comment: Yes, no mechanism for such distribution is in place. A FrozenDict will prevent change altogether, but that's not what you asked about - you have to wonder if disallowing change is all that much better than controlling it when needed. Again, you should think about why you want this to work this way to begin with. In most cases, there will be a better way to achieve the same.

Comment: Hai guys, sorry to interject here, but after reading the comments I realised I was understanding question as wrong. I update my answer below now after my revised suggestion, after I am understanding the ask with a little more clarity. Sorry for the initial confusion, btw.

Comment: Hey rv.kvetch, no worries, I learned from your initial answer as well! Your new solution seems legit. I will try and poke around with it to see how it interacts with situations as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for any initial confusion due to me not understanding the ask initially. Now, if I understand the problem statement correctly as below:

> [...] **however, if I directly set a `key: value`, the `@property.setter` is not being called.**

To enable any updates to the object `self.proxy_dict` - such as key assignment, `d['key'] = ...` - to trigger the property setter or `@price_dict.setter` method:

One option can be to define and use a `ProxyDict`, a custom `dict` implementation  which can internally call the desired setter method when `__setitem__()` is called, as indicated above.

```py
class ProxyDict(dict):

    # noinspection PyMissingConstructor, PyArgumentList
    def __init__(self, obj, prop: property, d: dict, _init=dict.__init__):
        # calls super().__init__()
        _init(self, d)
        # `prop` is a property object, and `prop.fset` is the setter function
        self._setter = lambda value, _set=prop.fset: _set(obj, value)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f'__setitem__() is called with key={key!r}, value={value!r}')
        self._setter({key: value})

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        if args:
            kwargs.update(*args)
        print(f'update() is called with {kwargs!r}')
        self._setter(kwargs)
```

Usage would then be as follows:

```py
class CoinJar:

    def __init__(self):
        self._price_dict = ProxyDict(
            self,
            CoinJar.price_dict,  # or: self.__class__.price_dict
            {'current': 0.0, 'high': 0.0, 'low': 0.0},
        )

    @property
    def price_dict(self):
        return self._price_dict

    @price_dict.setter
    def price_dict(self, pd: dict):

        print('setting price')

        try:
            new_price = float(pd.get('current'))
            price_is_set = True
        except ValueError as e:
            price_is_set = False
            print(f'Input cannot be converted to float {e}')

        # Exceptions
        if (not pd  # equivalent to: len(priceDict.keys()) == 0
                or not price_is_set):
            raise ValueError('setting illegal value')

        # setting high, low, current
        # noinspection PyUnboundLocalVariable
        changes = {'current': new_price}

        if new_price > self._price_dict['high']:
            changes['high'] = new_price
        curr_low = self._price_dict['low']
        if new_price < curr_low or curr_low == 0.0:
            changes['low'] = new_price

        # call `dict.update`, so we don't call this setter method again
        dict.update(self._price_dict, changes)


def main():
    btc = CoinJar()

    btc.price_dict = {'current': 500}  # This is calling priceDict.setter => accepts and performs the .setter expressions
    print(btc.price_dict)
    print()

    btc.price_dict['current'] = 250  # This is calling priceDict.setter
    print(btc.price_dict)
    print()

    btc.price_dict['current'] = 1000  # This is calling priceDict.setter
    print(btc.price_dict)
    print()

    btc.price_dict['flamingo'] = '500'  # This is calling priceDict.setter => raises Exception (as expected)
    print(btc.price_dict)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```py
setting price
{'current': 500.0, 'high': 500.0, 'low': 500.0}

__setitem__() is called with key='current', value=250
setting price
{'current': 250.0, 'high': 500.0, 'low': 250.0}

__setitem__() is called with key='current', value=1000
setting price
{'current': 1000.0, 'high': 1000.0, 'low': 250.0}

__setitem__() is called with key='flamingo', value='500'
setting price
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\path\to\script.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\<user>\path\to\script.py", line 80, in main
    btc.price_dict['flamingo'] = '500'  # This is calling priceDict.setter => raises Exception (as expected)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\path\to\script.py", line 12, in __setitem__
    self._setter({key: value})
  File "C:\Users\<user>\path\to\script.py", line 8, in <lambda>
    self._setter = lambda value, _set=prop.fset: _set(obj, value)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\path\to\script.py", line 40, in price_dict
    new_price = float(pd.get('current'))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

## Original Answer

This is my original answer, which was a direct result of me not understanding the problem or ask in its entirety.

Here, I understand the problem statement being defined as:

> **I am changing the dictionary by accessing the class `priceDict.__setitem__`. In this way, using a dictionary in a `@setter` way has not much use if someone can screw the Obj `<values>`.**

So to clarify, the ask as I understood it was an approach to raise an error when `priceDict.__setitem__` is called, as we only want the `priceDict` object to be mutable when the `@setter` method is called.

One option could be to use a custom `dict` implementation such as a `FrozenDict`, as shown below.

> Note that this is similar to how `dataclasses` does it, when you pass in `frozen=True` to create a frozen dataclass (attribute values can't be updated after object instantiation).

```py
# Raised when an attempt is made to modify a frozen dict.
class FrozenDictError(KeyError): pass


class FrozenDict(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        raise FrozenDictError(f'cannot assign to key {key!r}')

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise FrozenDictError(f'cannot assign to {self!r}')
```

Usage:

```py
class CoinJar:

    def __init__(self):
        self._priceDict = FrozenDict({'current': 0.0, 'high' : 0.0, 'low' : 0.0})

    @property
    def priceDict(self):
        return self._priceDict

    @priceDict.setter
    def priceDict(self, priceDict):

        print('setting price')

        try:
            newPrice = float(priceDict.get('current'))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f'Input cannot be converted to float {e}')

        # Exceptions
        if len(priceDict.keys()) == 0 or newPrice == None or type(newPrice) not in [int, float]:
            raise ValueError('setting illegal value')

        #setting high, low, current
        _priceDict = self._priceDict.copy()
        _priceDict['current'] = newPrice

        if newPrice > _priceDict['high']:
            _priceDict['high'] = newPrice
        if newPrice < _priceDict['low'] or _priceDict['low'] == 0.0:
            _priceDict['low'] = newPrice

        self._priceDict = FrozenDict(_priceDict)


def main():
    btc = CoinJar()
    btc.priceDict = {'current' : 500}           # This is calling priceDict.setter => accepts and performs the .setter expressions
    btc.priceDict['flamingo'] = 20              # This is not calling priceDict.setter => can do what i want, with 'current, high, flamingo, *'
    btc.priceDict = {'flamingo' : 500}          # This is calling priceDict.setter => raises Exception (as expected)
    print(btc)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
setting price
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\path\to\script.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\<user>\path\to\script.py", line 56, in main
    btc.priceDict['flamingo'] = 20              # This is not calling priceDict.setter => can do what i want, with 'current, high, flamingo, *'
  File "C:\Users\<user>\path\to\script.py", line 8, in __setitem__
    raise FrozenDictError(f'cannot assign to key {key!r}')
__main__.FrozenDictError: cannot assign to key 'flamingo'
```

### Using `dataclass(frozen=True)`

For a more robust implementation, you might consider refactoring to use a [frozen dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#frozen-instances) instead, along with [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.replace) to update a frozen instance:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, replace


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Price:
    current: float = 0.0
    high: float = 0.0
    low: float = 0.0


class CoinJar:

    def __init__(self):
        self._priceDict = Price()

    @property
    def priceDict(self):
        return self._priceDict

    @priceDict.setter
    def priceDict(self, priceDict):

        print('setting price')

        try:
            newPrice = float(priceDict.get('current'))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f'Input cannot be converted to float {e}')

        # Exceptions
        if len(priceDict.keys()) == 0 or newPrice == None or type(newPrice) not in [int, float]:
            raise ValueError('setting illegal value')

        #setting high, low, current
        changes = {'current': newPrice}

        if newPrice > self._priceDict.high:
            changes['high'] = newPrice

        if newPrice < self._priceDict.low or self._priceDict.low == 0.0:
            changes['low'] = newPrice

        self._priceDict = replace(self._priceDict, **changes)


def main():
    btc = CoinJar()
    print(btc.priceDict)

    btc.priceDict = {'current': 500}
    print(btc.priceDict)

    btc.priceDict = {'current': 1000, 'high': 200}
    print(btc.priceDict)

    btc.priceDict.flamingo = 20              # This is not calling priceDict.setter => can do what i want, with 'current, high, flamingo, *'
    btc.priceDict = {'flamingo': 500}          # This is calling priceDict.setter => raises Exception (as expected)
    print(btc)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```py
Price(current=0.0, high=0.0, low=0.0)
setting price
Price(current=500.0, high=500.0, low=500.0)
setting price
Price(current=1000.0, high=1000.0, low=500.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<usr>\path\to\script.py", line 62, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\<usr>\path\to\script.py", line 56, in main
    btc.priceDict.flamingo = 20              # This is not calling priceDict.setter => can do what i want, with 'current, high, flamingo, *'
  File "<string>", line 4, in __setattr__
dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'flamingo'
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Although I think the answer provided by Grismar will suit this case better. I managed to implement both solutions. Yours seems like a very nice solution in case the dict is only set at __init__ , to be never touched again. From what I've read in the documentation, and your solution, the way to make changes is by copying. In the long run, when the dict contains a lot of K: {}, etc. it will impact performance. Thanks both!

Comment: This is very similar to what `types.MappingProxyType` does.

Comment: @all Updated and revised as per notes in comments above, and after I am understanding the question or problem with now more clarity :-)